# Android studio Programmatic screenshot tries to take entire listview

Tags: java, android, listview, screenshot

I have a screenshot function that works great for most of my activities but in one activity I have a listview of 200+ items and when I call the function it seems to just hang at a black screen, I believe this is because it's trying to make a screenshot of the entire listview.

I can only think of two possible options,

1) would be if someone knows a better way to take the screenshot, I basically want it to be like a normal screenshot but the reason I want to do it programmatically is to hide certain things.

2) would be if there's a way to get a list of items that are in the physical view from the listview/adapter, that way I could repopulate the adapter and then set it back to normal after I'm done.

Thanks,

Screenshot code:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;

        String tempPass="";
        String tempUser="";

        try {
            //hides private data
            EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            tempPass = pass.getText().toString();
            tempUser = user.getText().toString();
            pass.setText("**************");
            user.setText("**************");

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            //converts image to bytearray for transfering
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            //unhides private data
            pass.setText(tempPass);
            user.setText(tempUser);

            //sends image to ImageViewActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,byteArray);
            startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say it hangs at a black screen do you mean that your app locks up or do you mean that the screenshot is all black?

Comment: @BenP. the app locks up, and although it doesn't throw any errors the "stop run" button on android studio turns grey and its just a black screen on the phone. The log i put in ImageViewActivity also doesn't appear